# How can I print only guessed letter from a word in their corresponding indicies?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a hangman game and I need to have to make a set of underscores that is the length of the word and when the user correctly guess a letter the corresponding space in the set of underscores becomes the correctly guess letter. How can I do this?

```
userGuess = raw_input('Enter a letter or the word:    ')
guessed = ''

def getWordList:
    #just getting a word from a tct file and returning a random word from it
    return word

def askForInput(userGuess):
    xx = str(userGuess)
    yy = xx.lower()
    return yy

def showWord:
    print'_ ' * len(word) #I know this part is wrong if I want to add the letters 
    print 'Guesses: %s' %guessed

if askForInput(userGuess) in word:
    print 'There are %ss' %askForInput(userGuess).upper()
    #now what can I do with showWord or how can I fix showWord?
```

Comment: sorry about the stupid formatting, i can't connect to the internet on my other computer

Comment: Do you have an actual question? And please, can you come up with a better question title?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, question is in last comment line

Comment: i know i could do something similar with lists and tuple assignments(i think that is what it is called) but i don't want tp have the square brakcets when i run the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
guess = "sol"
word = "stackoverflow"
hint = [l if l in guess else "_" for l in word]
print "".join(hint)
```

Here, `guess` is a string (or a list, or a set) holding all the letters the user has guessed so far, and `word`, obviously, is the word to guess. `hint` then is a list holding for each letter `l` in the word either that letter, if it is in the set of guessed letters, or an underscore. Finally, that hint is joined to a string and printed.

Output for this example would be `"s____o____lo_"`.

Comment: You don't need the intermediate list `hint`. Just use `print "".join(l if l in guess else "_" for l in word)`.

Comment: @martineau Sure, that was indeed my first version, too, but I decided to split it up and to explain one thing at a time.