# Random word guessing game

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, random, words

I want to create a word guessing game where the program randomly selects a word from my word list and the user has to guess the word.

- User can only guess one letter at a time.
- User is only allowed to have 6 failed guesses. (Loses when 6 failed attempts are used).
- User wins if he guess the complete word before 6 failed attempts is used.

So I'm facing quite a number of problems with my program:

1. How do I make the guessed letter stay on the blanks when it goes to the next round of guess?
2. If the word has two of the same letters, how do I display it on my blanks too?
3. How do I show all the user's missed letters for each round?

Here's what I did so far:

```
import random

wordlist = ['giraffe','dolphin',\
            'pineapple','durian',\
            'blue','purple', \
            'heart','rectangle']

#Obtain random word
randWord = random.choice(wordlist)

#Determine length of random word and display number of blanks
blanks = '_ ' * len(randWord)
print ()
print ("Word: ",blanks)


#Set number of failed attempts
count = 6

#Obtain guess
while True:
    print ()
    guess = input ("Please make a guess: ")   
    if len(guess) != 1:
        print ("Please guess one letter at a time!")
    elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
       print ("Please only guess letters!")

#Check if guess is found in random word
    for letters in randWord:
        if guess == letters:
            letterIndex = randWord.index(guess)
            newBlanks = blanks[:letterIndex*2] + guess + blanks[letterIndex*2+1:]
            print ("Guess is correct!")
        else:
            count -=1
            print ("Guess is wrong! ", count, " more failed attempts allowed.")
    print() 
    print("Word: ",newBlanks)
```

The results I hope to obtain (for randWord 'purple'):

```
Word: _ _ _ _ _ _ 
Missed: 
Please make a guess: l
Guess is correct!


Word: _ _ _ _ l _ 
Missed:
Please make a guess: z
Guess is wrong! 5 more failed attempts allowed.


Word: _ _ _ _ l _ 
Missed: z
Please make a guess: o
Guess is wrong! 4 more failed attempts allowed.


Word: _ _ _ _ l _ 
Missed: z, o
Please make a guess: p
Guess is correct!


Word: p _ _ p l _ 
Missed: z, o
Please make a guess: e
Guess is correct!


Word: p _ _ p l e 
Missed: z, o
Please make a guess: r
Guess is correct!


Word: p _ r p l e 
Missed: z, o
Please make a guess: u
Guess is correct!


Word: p u r p l e 
YOU WON!
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15454035/1639625)

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Whops, didn't see this. But he did not double-post... he triple-posted! Suggest closing the other questions with no answers.

Comment: @tobias_k yeah, I stopped counting...

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make the guessed letter stay on the blanks when it goes to
>   the next round of guess?

Just store string containing guessed letter and blanks for next round. You are recalculating it every time from `wordlist` (it can be also recalculated every time, but then you need to modify your search function for letters, see answer 2)

> If the word has two of the same letters, how do I display it on my blanks too?

Modify your search loop, it should continue searching after first matching letter is found.

`letterIndex = randWord.index(guess)` will return only first occurrence of guess in string.

> How do I show all the user's missed letters for each round?

Store them in separate string or list. So you can just print it every time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reusing the `newBlanks` string from the previous round, I suggest building it anew with `join` and a simple list comprehension, using a string `guessed` holding all the guesses, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15454196/1639625). Also note that your check for correct/incorrect letters does not work this way, but will decrease `count` for *each* letter of the word that is not the guessed letter. Use `if guess in randWord:` instead. Also, you can use `count` for the condition of the `while` loop, and `continue` with the next iteration of the loop if `guess` is not a single letter.

Putting it all together, your code could then look like this:

```
guessed = ""
while count >= 0:
    guess = input ("Please make a guess: ")   
    # ... check guess, continue if not a letter
    guessed += guess

    if guess in randWord:
        # ... print 'correct', else 'not correct', decrease count

    newBlanks = " ".join(c if c in guessed else "_" for c in randWord)
    print("Word: ",newBlanks)
```